# css3 columns leaves last column unfilled after first row when column count is more than 5

Tags: css

Hi I am learning to use columns in CSS3.
When I add a text to a card in my column it breaks when column count is more than 5.
You can see the text below card and image while the last column from row 2 is empty.

My HTML is

```css
.body-wrapper{
      width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .menu-list{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    .cards{
      white-space: normal;
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    #wrapper {
      vertical-align: top;  
      margin: 10px auto;
    }
    #columns {
      -webkit-column-count: 4 ;
      -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
      -webkit-column-fill: auto;
      -moz-column-count: 4  ;
      -moz-column-gap: 15px;
      -moz-column-fill: auto;
      column-count: 4 ;
      column-gap: 15px;
      column-fill: auto;
    }
    
    .pin {
      background: #FEFEFE;
      border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
      margin: 0 2px 15px;
      -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
      -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
      column-break-inside: avoid;
      padding: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
      opacity: 1;
    
    /*  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
      -o-transition: all .2s ease;
      transition: all .2s ease;*/
    }
    
    .pin img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .pin p {
      font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #333;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class='body-wrapper'>
     <div class='menu-list>....</div>
     <div class='cards'> ... </div>
     <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="columns">
       <div class="pin">...</div>
       <div class="pin">...</div>
       <div class="pin">...</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you, perhaps provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). So others can try it live and tweak along.

Comment: You're missing a closing quote `<div class='menu-list>....</div>` first off.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "float:left" instead. is simpler and more supported by browsers. In this case you need to clear floated element after 5th:

```
 .pin
 {
    float:left;
 }

 .pin:nth-child(5n + 1)
 {
    clear:left;
 }
```

The reason is that first thumb is taller and as you see, second row of floated elements start on the right of this one instead below it.